# Tiene objeto directo la oración-pregunta: Qué te gusta hacer?

Tags: sintaxis

En japonés la oración "Qué te gusta hacer?" tiene a la palabra `qué` sucedida por la partícula "o" que marca objetos directos. O sea, para los japoneses, `qué` es el objeto directo de esta oración. Es esto igual en español? Si/No/Porqué?

Comment: No sé cuál es el equivalente a *gustar* en japonés, pero ojo: en la mayoría de los idiomas, ese equivalente no funciona como en español. Ese verbo suele ser transitivo y el OD es lo que gusta, pero en español lo que gusta es el sujeto de la oración.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la oración:

- ¿Qué te gusta hacer?

el sujeto es "hacer qué" y, dentro de ese sujeto, "qué" es el objeto directo.

La respuesta puede ser un frase verbal con un verbo cualquiera, o con el verbo "hacer" seguido de objeto directo:

- Me gusta surfear.
- Me gusta hacer surf.

En las oraciones precedentes, "surfear" y "hacer surf" son sujeto. Dentro del sujeto "hacer surf", "surf" es objeto directo de "hacer".

Esto demuestra que en la pregunta "qué" es el objeto directo dentro del sujeto "hacer qué".

Por otro lado, "te" es el objeto indirecto (OI). Esto se comprueba por el hecho de que, al cambiar a tercera persona, se utiliza "le" (marca de OI) en lugar de "lo" (marca de OD):

- ¿Qué le gusta hacer?